# I can't seem to find the corrrect code for the Highest prime factor of a number in python 3

Tags: python, windows

```
b = []
a = int(input("Enter the number: "))
for i in range(2,a):
    if a%i == 0:
        pass
    else:
        for j in range(2,i):
            if i%j == 0:
                break
        else:
            b.append(i)            

for k in b:
    if max < k:
        max = k

print("max prime factor is this: ",max)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is close! But there are a few issues:

- You use a `range(2,a)` to check factors; this only contains integers from `2` to `a-1`, which misses the case for prime numbers (where `a` is the highest factor).  Using `range(2,a+1)` instead checks this.
- Your first conditional calls `pass` if the number is divisible by `i` (good use of `%`), but *this skips all factors of `a`*; you instead want to keep checking the number if `a % i == 0`, not `pass`
- You are using `max` incorrectly - `max` is a function, so when you say `if max < k`, this is just checking if a function is less than `k` (which isn't really a meaningful comparison), and your last `print` statement simply prints the string representation of Python's `max` function.  `max` instead can take an array as an argument, and return the maximum, so you just need to pass your list `b` to `max` like `max(b)`; there's no need for another loop!

Here's those points addressed, please ask if you have questions!  I liked the idea of using `break`, I also added a flag (`prime`) to make it easier to decide when to append it to `b`.

```
b = []
a = int(input("Enter the number: "))
for i in range(2,a+1):
    prime = True
    if a%i == 0:
        for j in range(2,i):
            if i%j == 0:
                prime = False
                break
        if prime:
            b.append(i)

print(max(b))
```